# Building a SQLite statement in JS and I'm not getting the full command I want

Tags: javascript, sqlite, webos

So, I'm building a SQLite statement in JS.  The problem is that it appears that %" is turning into "undefined"+ escaping the next character.  Here is the exact code:

The part of the sql statement that is messing up is this:

```
"and s.plainText like '%"+searchText+"%'";
```

There is more before that, but it all builds correctly.  So, in the program if I enter the following as the searchText:

```
foo
```

Then when I output the built sql statement to the console, I'm getting the following:

```
and s.plainText like 'undefinedoo%'
```

So, it appares that the %" is turning into undefined and causing the first letter of the searchText to be escaped.

How can I build this part of the sql statement correctly?  I have to use the " cause the statement contains '. and I have to use the % cause I need the wildcard to seach a string of text.

Comment: You should never, ever construct queries like this.

Answer (score 2):

If by JS you mean JavaScript, then this is not what's happening. Here's the jsfiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/Ka938/

Try it and you will see it's not a JS problem. The escaping is probably happening later in the process, when this gets to the server or something. Don't know the exact details to help there.

As a guess, if you are using PHP and (s)printf, then sending `%f` (where `f` is coming from `foo` example you used) is going to mean it expects a float - it would display an error, though.

As a side note, it seems that you are sending SQL from the client to the server. If so, it's probably a very bad idea to do this, especially if you are not doing any SQL escaping, as you are not per above. Take a look here:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

for basic details.

I'm not familiar with webOS, but check this SOq for something that looks to be handling SQL parameters correctly:

- [in webOS, I need a method that, using the input, will doe a sql select command and returns the restults as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260018/in-webos-i-need-a-method-that-using-the-input-will-doe-a-sql-select-command-an)

Definitively worth doing some more investigation about how to do this properly in webOS - [Google](http://www.google.com/) is your friend.

Comment: first off, that JS Fiddle is COOL.  I'll bookmark that one.  That said, this is all on webOS (cell phone OS) and so the client and server are one far as I know.  Anyway, I know no other way to handle this.  Last, I have the logging command to output the built SQL statment as the very next statement in the code so nothing else is happening to it in the meantime.    Perhaps this problem is more specific to webOS?

Comment: jsfiddle is really very nice. As of webOS, I'm not familiar with it to help you more. In general, sending SQL (or parts of SQL) from the client to the server without escaping/validating is very dangerous - check the Wikipedia link. So don't do it. For testing, try putting either `%%` or `\%` instead of `%`, might help. And again - don't allow SQL injection, it will bite you down the road.

Answer (score 0):

The Mojo.Log commands processes the string that you pass a little like the printf function in C. That is you can specify some placeholders that will be filled with the value of the passed parameters. An example is a thousand words so:

```
Mojo.Log.info("My string is '%s' and my number is '%f'", strData, numData);
```

will print

```
My string is 'aaa' and my number is '1'
```

if strData is 'aaa' and numData is 1.

So most likely your string is built correctly, but printing it will try to replace the %f from %foo% with a parameter. The parameter is never passed so it is undefined. You should see the correct output if you use something else rather than 'foo' to test (try 'bbb').

For more information check out the documentation for [Mojo.Log](https://developer.palm.com/content/api/reference/mojo/classes/mojo-log.html).

**PS** That being said it's not a good practice to construct your SQL statements like that, so I don't recommend it. Easy to do, but hard to read and maintain later :)